# c# winforms DataGridViewRow.Index and Count

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What is wrong with this code

```
for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Rows.Count;)  
{
    MessageBox.Show(dgv.Rows[i].Index.ToString());
}
```

I'm getting endless MsgBoxes displaying allways and only value "1"
dgv has six rows.

Comment: if any answer is useful for you vote it up and mark it as BEST ANSWER, by click on Tick and make it green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to place i++

and also i = 0; if i = 1 you will be miss first row of gridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count;i++)  
{
    MessageBox.Show(dgv.Rows[i].Index.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Should I Laugh or Cry! ThankYou. BTW it seems that i++ is not necessery in the sintax. Clear logic: i=1; i<x is enough. isn't it? Should be ?

Comment: `i = 0` is the initializer. `i < x` is the condition. But `i++` is the incrementor. If you will not increment `i` how will `i` reach the value of `x`. `i` will always remain 0 or 1 depending on your initializer. This causes an infinite loop.

Comment: I cannot reach the value of x because syntax is requering incrementor. But imagine the same syntax without incrementor. Is it normal that dgvRowIndex is an integer, and not a decimal. Should be normal to assumed.